# Jooq's fetchMaps returns timezoned data with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

I have a generic service that returns data via rest controller - here is the method in `Repository`:

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> read(@NonNull final Table<?> table,
                                      @NonNull final Collection<Field<?>> fields,
                                      @NonNull final Collection<Condition> conditions,
                                      @NonNull final Integer offset,
                                      @NonNull final Integer limit,
                                      final SortField<?> sortField) {
    return dslContext
            .select(fields)
            .from(table)
            .where(conditions)
            .orderBy(sortField)
            .offset(offset)
            .limit(limit)
            .fetchMaps();
}
```

The returned `List<Map<String, Object>>` contains data from MySQL db. The problem is with `datetime` fields - in db we don't store timezones but returned `Object` is of type `Timestamp` has underneath `GregorianCalendar` type which gives `2018-07-05T00:00:00.000+0200` for value `2018-07-05 00:00:00.000` in db. It adds probably default timezone (GMT +2).

Is there a way to simply tell jOOQ to convert `datetime` and `date` fields from db to `LocalDateTime` and `LocalDate` instead of `Timestamp` and `Date`?I know it uses JDBC underneath and the problem is probably there but maybe there is a smart way of fixing that.

I could do some instanceOf checks in additional mapper but would like to avoid it because it would make the code much more difficult and instanceOf checks are just ugly.

EDIT:
Using jooq 3.9.5 and java 8.

Comment: How do you create the `fields` parameter when you pass that into your method? Because the answer is in what data type is associated with your `datetime` and `date` fields...

Comment: Fields in that context are not filled in -> are an empty list so I guess all fields are returned. In given example I have only created_at > XXX and created_at <XXX conditions (apart from limit, table and offset ofc)

Comment: OK, then what are the fields contained in `table` (which is what is going to be projected and what you're having trouble with)?

Comment: lots of, but some of them are: created_at -> datetime which is Timestamp type and same about end_at -> datetime and parsed as Timestamp with +0200 timezone when on db it's without a timezone.

Comment: You can explain this to me with some prose, and I will still be unable to help, or you could show some code to help reproduce this. :) Here are some useful guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve